# Como hacer que funcione una usb wireless en un pc de escritorio

Tags: windows

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí], [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí], necesito saber como puedo hacer para que funcione el usb, ya intente pero no lo he logrado

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no parece tener nada que ver con la programación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prueba con alguno de estos drivers.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vg44u4pulz1p0rk/AABKtnpxnX5rqM5w21fOwbD2a

https://mega.nz/#!CZpVUQ4L!fw580cnU3FNGKRJIn1awOIoDcCbx-FFl9U30RVgZFDg

saludos.